# How do I make the "action" of this card game keep executing until a winner is found?

Tags: java, loops, playing-cards

I created this card game that asks the user for an action. "attack" and "swap". they both work fine on the first execution, but how do I make it so that the system keeps asking the user for an action until one of the player wins?

This contains my code for the class GameMaster that the GameConsole will reference. It has links to two other classes I have called Player and Card.

```
import java.util.*;
public class GameMaster
{
private int turnCounter = 0;
private ArrayList<Card> deck;
private boolean isThereWinner; 
private Player player1;
private Player player2;
public GameMaster (Player a, Player b) //initializes values
{
    turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
    player1 = a;
    player2 = b;
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    assembleDeck();
    dealCard();
}
private void assembleDeck() //given order of cards
{
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Aquira", 174, 26 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Brawn", 130, 48 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Cerulea", 162, 29 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Demi", 147, 28 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Elba", 155, 37 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Fye", 159, 42 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Glyede", 129, 26 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Hydran", 163, 35 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Ivy", 146, 45 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Jet", 170, 24 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Kineti", 139, 21 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Levi", 160, 43 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Meadow", 134, 29 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Naidem", 165, 26 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Omi", 145, 21 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Puddles", 170, 34 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Quarrel", 151, 29 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Raven", 168, 32 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Surge", 128, 27 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Takiru", 140, 26 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Ustelia", 163, 47 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Verwyn", 145, 25 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Wyverin", 158, 32 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Fairy", "Xios", 155, 27 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Dragon", "Yora", 159, 44 ) );
    deck.add( new Card( "Ghost", "Zulu", 125, 46 ) );
}
public java.lang.String play (java.lang.String action) // lets player enter action swap or attack
{
   if (turnCounter%2==1) //player 1's turn
   {
        if (action.equals("swap")) // if player one enters "swap"
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            System.out.println("   "+player1.getName() + " swaps out " + player1.getActiveCard().getName()+".");
            player1.swap();

        }
        else if (action.equals("attack")) // if player one enter "attack"
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            System.out.println("   "+player1.getName() + " attacks with " + player1.getActiveCard().getName()+".");
            dealDamage(player1.getActiveCard(), player2.getActiveCard());

            if (player2.getActiveCard().getHealth()<1) //if player 2's health goes below 1
            {
                player2.discard();
                System.out.println("   "+player2.getName() + " discards " + player2.getActiveCard().getName());
                player2.drawCard(deck.get(0));
                System.out.println(player2.getName() + " draws " + deck.get(0)+".");
                if (deck.size()==0) // if there are no more cards in the deck
                {
                    System.out.println("The deck is empty.");
                }
                player1.claimToken();
                System.out.println("   "+player1.getName() + " gets a token!");
                if (player1.getTokens()==3) //if player1 kills three of player2's cards = 3 tokens
                {
                    hasWinner();
                    System.out.println(player1.getName() + " wins!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (turnCounter%2==0) //player 2's turn
    {
        if (action.equals("swap")) //if player 2 chooses "swap"
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            System.out.println("   "+player2.getActiveCard().getName() + " swaps out " + player2.getActiveCard().getName());
            player2.swap();

        }
        else if (action.equals("attack")) //if player two chooses "attack"
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            System.out.println("   "+player2.getName() + " attacks with " + player2.getActiveCard());
            dealDamage(player2.getActiveCard(), player1.getActiveCard());
            if (player1.getActiveCard().getHealth()<1) //if player 1's health drops below 1
            {
                player1.discard();
                System.out.println("   "+player1.getName() + " discards " + player1.getActiveCard().getName());
                player1.drawCard(deck.get(0));
                System.out.println("   "+player1.getName() + " draws " + deck.get(0)+".");
                if (deck.size()==0) //if there are no more cards in the deck
                {
                    System.out.println("The deck is empty.");
                }
                player2.claimToken();
                System.out.println("   "+player2.getName() + " gets a token!");
                if (player2.getTokens()==3) //if player 2 kills 3 of player1's cards = get three tokens
                {
                    hasWinner();
                    System.out.println(player2.getName() + " wins!");
                }
            }



        }

   }
   return "";
}
public boolean checkResistance(java.lang.String type1, java.lang.String type2) //checks for resistance
{
    if (type1.equals("Dragon")&&type2.equals("Ghost"))
        return true;
    else if (type1.equals("Ghost")&&type2.equals("Fairy"))
        return true; 
    else if (type1.equals("Fairy")&&type2.equals("Dragon"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean checkWeakness(java.lang.String type1, java.lang.String type2) //checks for weakness
{
    if (type1.equals("Dragon")&&type2.equals("Fairy"))
        return true;
    else if (type1.equals("Fairy")&&type2.equals("Ghost"))
        return true;
    else if (type1.equals("Ghost")&&type2.equals("Dragon"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public java.lang.String dealCard() //altertately deals cards to each player at the start of the game
{
    if (turnCounter==1)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            player1.playerHand.add(deck.get(0));
            deck.remove(0);
            System.out.println(player1.getName() + " draws " + player1.playerHand.get(i).getName()+".");
            player2.playerHand.add(deck.get(0));
            deck.remove(0);
            System.out.println(player2.getName() + " draws " + player2.playerHand.get(i).getName()+".");
        }
    }
    else if (turnCounter%2==1) //odd turns = player 1
    {
        if (player1.playerHand.size()==5)
        {
            System.out.println(player1.getName() + "'s hand is full.");
        }
        else if (player1.playerHand.size()<5)
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            player1.playerHand.add(deck.get(0));
            deck.remove(0);
            System.out.println(player1.getName() + " draws " + player1.playerHand.get(0).getName()+".");
        }
        turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
    }
    else if (turnCounter%2==0) //even turns = player2
    {
        if (player2.playerHand.size()==5)
        {
            System.out.println(player2.getName() + "'s hand is full.");
        }
        else if (player2.playerHand.size()<5)
        {
            turnCounter = turnCounter + 1;
            player2.playerHand.add(deck.get(0));
            deck.remove(0);
            System.out.println(player2.getName() + " draws " + player2.playerHand.get(0).getName()+".");
        }
        turnCounter = turnCounter;
    }


    return "";
}
public java.lang.String dealDamage(Card inPlay, Card target) //calculates how much damage a card receives, taking into account weakness and resistance
{
    if (checkResistance(target.getType(),inPlay.getType())==true) //if there is resistance
    {
        System.out.println("      "+target.getType() +" is resistant to "+inPlay.getType()+".");
        target.takeHalfDamage(inPlay.getPower());
        checkResistance(inPlay.getType(),target.getType());
        System.out.println("   "+inPlay.getName()+" deals "+inPlay.getPower()/2+" damage on "+target.getName()+".");
        System.out.println("   "+target.getName()+" has "+target.getHealth()+" left.");
    }
    else if (checkWeakness(target.getType(),inPlay.getType())==true) //if there is weakness
    {
        System.out.println("      "+target.getType() +" is weak to "+inPlay.getType()+".");
        target.takeDoubleDamage(inPlay.getPower());
        System.out.println("   "+inPlay.getName()+" deals "+inPlay.getPower()*2+" damage on "+target.getName()+".");
        System.out.println("   "+target.getName()+" has "+target.getHealth()+" left.");
    }
    else //if it does normal damage
    {
        target.takeDamage(inPlay.getPower());
        System.out.println("   "+inPlay.getName()+" deals "+inPlay.getPower()+" damage on "+target.getName()+".");
        System.out.println("   "+target.getName()+" has "+target.getHealth()+" left.");
    }
    return "";
}
public boolean hasWinner() //as long as there is no winner, it is false
{
    return true;
}
public java.lang.String gameReport() //prints out a summary of a game as well as each player's stats
{
    System.out.println("___=== GAME SUMMARY ===___");
    System.out.println("This game lasted "+turnCounter+" turns.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(player1.getName());
    System.out.println("        "+player1.statusReport());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(player2.getName());
    System.out.println("        "+player2.statusReport());
    return "";

}
```

This is the runner I currently have called GameConsole.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameConsole
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    Scanner player = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Player 1: ");
    String player1String = player.next(); // input player1 name
    System.out.print("Player 2: "); 
    String player2String = player.next(); // input player2 name
    System.out.println("Welcome, "+player1String+" and "+player2String+"!");
    System.out.println("The game begins.");
    Player player1 = new Player(player1String); // turns player1's String name into an object
    Player player2 = new Player(player2String); // turns player2's Strign name into an object
    System.out.println();
    GameMaster game = new GameMaster(player1,player2); // uses the player1 and player2 objects as objects for the GameMAster
    System.out.println();
    Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Attack or Swap? ");
    String whatMove = move.next(); //input for action

    //i tried putting this in a while-loop but the action won't even execute once
    game.play(whatMove); // executes play for action
    }
}
```

When I run it, this is what happens //user input is in ALL CAPS

```
Player 1: ADAM
Player 2: BOB
Welcome, ADAM and BOB!
The game begins.
//space
ADAM draws Aquira.
BOB draws Brawn.
ADAM draws Cerulea.
BOB draws Demi.
ADAM draws Elba.
BOB draws Fye.
ADAM draws Glyede.
BOB draws Hydran.
ADAM draws Ivy.
BOB draws Jet.
//space
Attack or Swap? ATTACK    //SWAP works fine too
   ADAM attacks with Aquira.
      Ghost is weak to Dragon.
   Aquira deals 52 damage on Brawn.
   Brawn has 78 left.
//and then it just stops
```

tbh I'm not completely sure if my code works, but because I don't know how to repeat the action, I wouldn't know...I hope what I said made sense...I'm new to CS so I would appreciate any amount of help.

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of code that demonstrates your problem. The more unnecessary code you post, the less the likelihood of anyone reading it all. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not undestand what is an issue here. Create loop that loops until there is a winner. Also there should be other ways to quit game

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need some sort of loop. I'd recommend a while loop around the code that stands for 1 round. (I assume that 1 round is played in the main method)

It depends on when your game has to end as well, for example if your game has to end after 10 rounds you could do something like:

```
while(game.turnCounter <= 10) { // Code for one round goes here };
```

Else you could make a boolean that checks if the game is finished.

```
while(!game.gameIsFinshed) { // Code for one round goes here };
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it only runs once - the `play()` command is only called once in your code, outside of any loops. As it is right now, the code is running perfectly as intended.

You need to put it in a loop, most likely a `while` loop based on your requirements. The comments said you've already tried that and it didn't work, so why don't you show that code? That way we can at least figure out what's making the code behave not as intended.

By the way, the `hasWinner()` function you have seems to be unfinished, as all it does is return `true` all the time. If you used `while(!hasWinner())` as the while condition, of course it won't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last couple lines with this:

```
String whatMove = "QUIT";
do {
    whatMove = move.next(); //input for action
    (whatMove.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) ? break : game.play(whatMove);
} while (true);
```

This gives you a loop and a command option to end play mid-game.